# Return a type T in C++

Tags: c++, entity

How can I make something like this in C++:

C# code:

```
   public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component 
        {
        foreach (var c in Components) 
        {
            if (c is T) return (T)c;
        }
        foreach (var c in componentsToAdd) 
        {
            if (c is T) return (T)c;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @user4581301 Not particularly helpful, he's after something a lot more specific.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I'm a little unsure. Are you focusing on the type constraint of `T` or are you trying to understand templates (C# generics)? As it is, this question is hard to understand.

Comment: Couldn't this be done by simply using [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)? If not, could you give a little more info about what you are trying to do, and the collections that contains the `Component`?

Answer (score 1):

Returning a generic type 'T' is easy, but there's no (nice) equivalent to C# constraints (but see callyalater's comment):

```
   public:
   template<typename T> // where T : Component - no equivalent
   T GetComponent()
   {
        for (auto c : Components)
        {
            if (dynamic_cast<T>(c) != nullptr)
            {
                return static_cast<T>(c);
            }
        }
        for (auto c : componentsToAdd)
        {
            if (dynamic_cast<T>(c) != nullptr)
            {
                return static_cast<T>(c);
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
   }
```

Comment: You can emulate type constraints like this: `#define U_EXTENDS_V(U,V) template<typename U, typename _ = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<V, U>::value>::type>` or 
`#define U_SUPER_V(U,V)  template<typename U, typename _ = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<U, V>::value>::type>`, but it is really ugly.

Comment: I've had to force type constraints at work and after a lot of research found this method that works (and is like Java's type constraints), but is really ugly and I hated myself every time I had to use it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is actually quite complicated. C++ does not have native type reflection, so you cannot determine (easily) at run-time whether or not a type is a subclass of another. Real-time type checking of this kind has to be done manually.

This won't be a complete solution, but it should get you part of the way there:

---

This is a similar piece of code from my own engine. The important bit here is the `template` above the function declaration.

```
map<type_index, shared_ptr<GameComponent>> type_components;

template<typename T = enable_if<is_base_of<GameComponent, T>::value>::type>
shared_ptr<T> get_component() const
{
    static const std::type_index TYPE_INDEX = typeid(T);

    auto component = type_components.find(TYPE_INDEX);

    if (component == type_components.end())
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return static_pointer_cast<T, GameComponent>(*component);
}

template<typename T = enable_if<is_base_of<GameComponent, T>::value>::type>
shared_ptr<T> add_component()
{
    static const type_index TYPE_INDEX = typeid(T);

    auto component = make_shared<T>();

    type_components.insert(make_pair(TYPE_INDEX, component));

    return component;
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
get_component<DerivedGameComponent>();
```

If the type passed in is not a base of `GameComponent`, the compiler will throw an error.

The limitations of the system compared to the C# equivalent are fairly obvious. First and most obviously, it knows nothing about the type hierarchy. For example:

```
struct A : GameComponent { };
struct B : A { };

add_component<B>();
get_component<A>();
```

The `get_component` call would return null, because it doesn't know that `B` is a subclass of `A`. To get around this in my own project, all my game components and objects are embedded into Python, and I enlist it to do the type and hierarchy checking for me.

Comment: I've done this kind of type constraint before (see my comment in @DaveDoknjas answer above), but I put it into a macro definition, because it is so long and can be hard to understand. It is also annoying because the compiler error doesn't give you a very useful error message when it complains and it can be hard to track down in your code.